# How to collect industry usage of data persistence technologies?

Tags: persistence

In our organization, we are using various data access/persistence technologies in different projects. The ones used till now are Hibernate, JPA, Spring Data JPA, JDBC, Spring JDBC, MyBatis, and QueryDSL.

How do I find out what is the industry usage of these technologies? i.e. which is used more widely than others - or even a pie chart showing the distribution of such technologies.

Also curious to know which technologies are being used by major players - like big silicon valley companies, or prominent investment firms. Do you know a way to find this data?

Can the firms like Forrester or Gartner would have such a data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should you really care? You could chose a technology that, for various reasons, you trust or prefer...

Comment: Look at the job postings. This may vary by location and possibly industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess most of this information is not freely available on the internet. So the best approach is probably to make a survey, call or email 100 top IT companies and just *ask* them. However, if you don't have a name like "Forrester" or "Gartner" on your business card, it is likely you won't get much response. Alternatively, you could charge someone from the big research companies to collect this information for you (note, you did not ask for a *cheap* solution).

Answer (score 0):

1. why do you even care?
2. you won't get a response from most companies as they'd consider it a company secret what they use
3. what are your criteria? Many companies would have investigated a lot of things, before maybe adopting one or two of them. And then they may no longer be used in new projects.
4. why do you even care? Use what's appropriate for your project, not what's "popular".

Comment: All these are open source technologies. Since when did using open source become company secret?
Our management wants to gauge the industry trend, and make sure we are not deviating too much from what is being accepted in the industry at present. Although it's a good point that the fact someone is using a technology, does not mean that they have made a right choice. I guess I will know the full picture only if I talk with the architect in a company.

Comment: @PA it doesn't matter whether it's open source or not. Many companies don't want it known publicly what 3rd party tools and libraries they use, period.